# If one sub category in multiple model shows significance, can I conclude that the WHOLE variable is significant?

Tags: regression

I have a question related to regression.

If I have the variable "marital status", with different categories of single, married, widowed, etc. I ran a multiple linear model with my outcome: only "married" was significant, while the others (single, widowed) were not. But the whole model was significant.

How can I interpret this? Can I conclude that that the whole variable of marital status is significant??

Comment: As you did not provide much details, I can only guess you ran something like an anova or F test on the whole model, this will test all your coefficients are zero, which is your model is not true, as one variable is significant

Comment: You can conclude that the effect of that variable is most likely not zero, but without seeing your data, results, can't comment much beyond this